# mp3 encoder in iOS with arm64

Tags: ios, iphone, mp3, lame

I am using mp3 encoder in my app. I got project from Github reference: - https://github.com/rpplusplus/iOSMp3Recorder

This project working fine with armv7.But apple do not accept my app because i have removes arm64 support.

This code doesn't work with arm64.Can anyone suggest me any alternate or compatible this project for arm64.

I got this error when i add arm64

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/ranjitsingh/Documents/Projects/LabelVoice/libmp3lame.dylib, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/ranjitsingh/Documents/Projects/LabelVoice/libmp3lame.dylib (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_lame_close", referenced from:
      -[RecordViewController toMp3] in RecordViewController.o
  "_lame_encode_buffer_interleaved", referenced from:
      -[RecordViewController toMp3] in RecordViewController.o
  "_lame_encode_flush", referenced from:
      -[RecordViewController toMp3] in RecordViewController.o
  "_lame_init", referenced from:
      -[RecordViewController toMp3] in RecordViewController.o
  "_lame_init_params", referenced from:
      -[RecordViewController toMp3] in RecordViewController.o
  "_lame_set_VBR", referenced from:
      -[RecordViewController toMp3] in RecordViewController.o
  "_lame_set_in_samplerate", referenced from:
      -[RecordViewController toMp3] in RecordViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please Try this link, 
https://libraries.io/cocoapods/mp3lame-for-ios/0.1.1

Comment: I also have same issue @singh